Details in the proof of a local version of Cartan-Ambrose-Hicks theorem
I am very sorry for the long length, but most of it is notions conventions and there isn't much argument and deduction.

Let $ M^{n} $ and $ \bar{M}^{n} $ be two Riemannian manifolds. Fix base points $ p \in M, \bar{p} \in \bar{M} $ and an isometry $ I: T_p M \rightarrow T_{\bar{p}} \bar{M}$.
For $ r>0 $ sufficiently small, define the diffeomorphism
$$\varphi=\exp _{\bar{p}} \circ I \circ \exp _{p}^{-1}: B_{r}(p) \rightarrow B_{r}(\bar{p}).$$
Denote by $ P_{\gamma} :T_{\gamma(0)}M\to T_{\gamma(a)}M$ the parallel transport along the curve $ \gamma:[0,a]\to M$, and $ R, \bar{R} $ the curvature tensors of $ M^{n} $ and $ \bar{M}^{n}$, respectively. For a geodesic $ \gamma $ in $ B_{r}(p) $ starting from $ p$, write $ \varphi(\gamma)=\bar{\gamma}$, and set $ I_{\gamma}= P_{\bar{\gamma}} \circ I \circ P_{-\gamma}$. Then we have:
Lemma. With the above notations, if for all geodesics $ \gamma $ in $ B_{r}(p) $ starting from $ p $ and any tangent vectors $ X, Y $ and $ Z $ at the ending point of $ \gamma$, it holds
$$I_{\gamma} R(X,Y)Z=\bar{R}(I_{\gamma} X,I_{\gamma} Y)I_{\gamma} Z.$$
Then $ \varphi $ is an isometry and $\varphi_*=I_{\gamma}$.
Partial proof. Let $ \gamma:[0, a] \rightarrow B_{r}(p) $ be the unit speed geodesic from $ p $ to $ q \in B_{r}(p) $, $ X \in T_q M$, and $ J $ be the Jacobi field along $ \gamma $ with $ J(0)=0 $ and $ J(a)=X$.
For $t\in[0, a]$, write $ \gamma_{t}=\left.\gamma\right|_{[0, t]}$, and set $ \bar{J}(t)=I_{\gamma_{t}} J(t)$. By our assumption on the curvature, $ \bar{J} $ is a Jacobi field along $ \bar{\gamma}:=\varphi(\gamma)$, and $ |\bar{J}(t)|=|J(t)|$. So it suffices to show that $ \varphi_{*} J(t)=\bar{J}(t)$.
From the relation $ \bar{J}(t)=P_{\bar{\gamma}_{t}} \circ I \circ P_{-\gamma_{t}}(J(t)) $ it follows that $ I\left(J^{\prime}(0)\right)=\bar{J}^{\prime}(0)$.

I can't see why $ \bar{J} $ is a Jacobi field along $ \bar{\gamma}$ and why $I\left(J^{\prime}(0)\right)=\bar{J}^{\prime}(0)$. For the former, my attempt:
$$\bar\gamma'(0)=\exp _{\bar{p}*} \circ I_* \circ {\exp _{p}^{-1}}_*(\gamma'(0))={\rm Id}\circ I_* \circ{\rm Id}(\gamma'(0))=I(\gamma'(0)).$$
So
$$I_{\gamma_t}(\gamma'(t))=P_{\bar{\gamma_t}} \circ I \circ P_{-\gamma_t}(\gamma'(t))=P_{\bar{\gamma_t}} \circ I(\gamma'(0))=P_{\bar{\gamma_t}}(\bar\gamma'(0))=\bar\gamma'(t).$$
Therefore
\begin{align*}
\nabla_{\bar\gamma'}\nabla_{\bar\gamma'}\bar J+\bar R(\bar J,\bar\gamma')\bar\gamma'&=\nabla_{\bar\gamma'}\nabla_{\bar\gamma'}\bar J+\bar R(I_{\gamma_{t}}J,I_{\gamma_{t}}\gamma')I_{\gamma_{t}}\gamma'\\
&=\nabla_{\bar\gamma'}\nabla_{\bar\gamma'}\bar J+I_{\gamma_{t}}R(J,\gamma')\gamma'\\
&=\nabla_{\bar\gamma'}\nabla_{\bar\gamma'}\bar J-I_{\gamma_{t}}(\nabla_{\gamma'}\nabla_{\gamma'}J)\\
&\overset?=0.
\end{align*}
I got stuck at "?" at the end. Any help would be appreciated!

I have not gone though your proof, but somewhere in your proof you have to use the fact that for any Jacobi field $J$, $$\nabla{\gamma'}J = \nabla_J\gamma'.$$ To interpret the right side, use the fact that $\gamma$ is part of a $1$-parameter family of geodesics and $J$ is obtained by differentiating with respect to that parameters.

@Deane I know it. It comes from pushforwards formula of Lie Brackets$$F_*[X,Y]=[F_*X,F_*Y].$$So we can get$$[J,\gamma']=0.$$

It's a subtle point, but in fact the formula $$F_*[X,Y] = [F_*X,F_Y] $$ is not true. For example, if $F_$ is the constant map, then the right side isn't even defined. You have to impose assumptions on $F$. The simplest is assuming that $F$ is an embedding. But that's not good enough for deriving the equation for the Jacobi field. If you read carefully any exposition of Jacobi fields, you'll see that they never mention the pushforward.

@Deane Here $F$ is a variation $\alpha$, so$$[J,\gamma']=\left[\frac{\partial\alpha}{\partial s},\frac{\partial\alpha}{\partial t}\right]=\alpha_*\left[\frac{\partial}{\partial s},\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\right]=0.$$

Sorry. I'm being careless. Nothing I've said is relevant to your question.

@Deane The remaining proof is:
Since both $J$ and $\bar{J}$ are Jacobi fields vanishing at $t=0$, they are given by
$$J(t)=\left(\exp {p}\right){* t \gamma^{\prime}(0)}\left(t J^{\prime}(0)\right), \quad \bar{J}(t)=\left(\exp {\bar{p}}\right){* t \bar{\gamma}^{\prime}(0)}\left(t \bar{J}^{\prime}(0)\right)$$
From this and the definition of $\varphi$, it follows $\varphi_{*} J(t)=\bar{J}(t)$. This completes the proof of the lemma.

$\newcommand\Jbar{\overline{J}}\newcommand\Mbar{\overline{M}}$Let me sketch another proof.
Fix an orthonormal frame $(e_1, \dots, e_n)$ at $p$ and for each $v \in B_r(p)$, parallel translate the frame along the radial geodesic with initial velocity $v$. Let $J_1, \dots, J_n$ be Jacobi fields such that $J_k(0) = e_k$ and $\nabla_vJ(0) = 0$. Each Jacobi field can written in terms of the orthonormal frame and a matrix $J$ as $$J_k = J_k^je_j. $$ The Jacobi equation implies that the matrix $J$ along the radial geodesic satisfies the ODE
$$ J'' + JK = 0,\ J(0) = \text{ identity matrix and}\ J'(0) = 0, $$ where $K$ is the matrix with components $$K^j_k = g(e_j,R(\gamma',e_k)\gamma').$$
Now let $(\bar{e}_1,\dots, \bar{e}_n)$ be the parallel translation of $(I(e_1), \dots, I(e_n))$ along the radial geodesic with initial velocity $I(v)$. Let $\Jbar_1, \dots, \Jbar_n$ be the Jacobi fields and $\Jbar$ be the matrix defined in the same way as above. The assumption of the lemma implies that
$$ \Jbar'' + \Jbar K = 0,\ \Jbar(0) = \text{ identity matrix},\ \Jbar'(0) = 0, $$
and therefore $J = \Jbar$ along the respective radial geodesics.
On the other hand, the metric tensor in the exponential coordinates defined using $(e_1, \dots, e_n)$ is given by
$$ g_{jk} = J_j^iJ_k^i. $$
Since $J = \Jbar$, it follows that $g_{jk} = \bar{g}_{jk}$ along each radial geodesic in $M$ and its counterpart in $\Mbar$. From this it is straightforward to show that the map $\varphi$ is an isometry.

I came up with a simpler idea while reading Riemannian geometry by do carmo just now and posted it

Our general ideas are indeed similar

For why $ \bar{J} $ is a Jacobi field along $ \bar{\gamma}$ :
Let $e_i(t)$, $i=1,\cdots,n$ be an parallel frame along $\gamma$. Then $\bar e_i(t):=I_{\gamma_t}e_i(t)$, $i=1,\cdots,n$ is an parallel frame along $\bar\gamma$. Write
$$J(t)=\sum_iy_i(t)e_i(t).$$
Since $\bar{J}(t)=I_{\gamma_{t}} J(t)$, we have
$$\bar J(t)=\sum_iy_i(t)\bar e_i(t).$$
Therefore
\begin{align*}
\nabla_{\bar\gamma'}\nabla_{\bar\gamma'}\bar J(t)-I_{\gamma_{t}}(\nabla_{\gamma'}\nabla_{\gamma'}J(t))&=\sum_iy_i''(t)\bar e_i(t)-I_{\gamma_{t}}\left(\sum_iy_i''(t)e_i(t)\right)\\
&=\sum_iy_i''(t)\bar e_i(t)-\sum_iy_i''(t)\bar e_i(t)\\
&=0.
\end{align*}
For why $I\left(J^{\prime}(0)\right)=\bar{J}^{\prime}(0)$ :
\begin{align*}
I\left(J^{\prime}(0)\right)&=I\left(\sum_iy_i'(0)e_i(0)\right)\\
&=\sum_iy_i'(0)\bar e_i(0)\\
&=\bar J'(0).
\end{align*}
